# Display List in View via TempData or ViewBag

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

i have some problems and don't know what to do. I tried several solution for this but that foreach loop turns always "null".
 It failed in that foreach and says 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
Here is my Controller;

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public int count;
    private readonly IConfiguration configuration;
    private IHostingEnvironment _env;
    private readonly string _webRootPath;
    public string _dir;
    public HomeController(IConfiguration config, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        this.configuration = config;
        _webRootPath = env.WebRootPath;
    }
    public async Task<IActionResult> FileUpload(IEnumerable<IFormFile> files)
    {
        var targetFolder = Path.Combine(_webRootPath, "images");
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            count = 0;
            var fileName = $"{Guid.NewGuid()}.png";
            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(targetFolder, fileName), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                file.CopyTo(fileStream);
                count++;
            }
            string publicPath = "/images/" + fileName;
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                List<string> test = new List<string>();
                test.Add(publicPath.ToString());
                TempData["link"] = test;      
            }

        }
        return new RedirectResult(@"Privacy");
    }
    public IActionResult Privacy()   //Privacy name here is just example it can change
    {
        //List<string> Data = TempData["link"] as List<string>;
        //TempData.Keep();
        //ViewBag.link = Data;
        return View(TempData["link"] as string[]);
    }
}
```

And this is my privacy .cshtml;

```
    <label>Link:</label><br />
        @*<input type="text" name="link" size="100" value="@TempData["link"]" /><br />*@
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <textarea cols="102" rows="5" disabled="disabled" style="resize:none;">@item</textarea><br />
        }
```

Comment: Have you debugged it to see where in the loop it is failing?

Comment: I want to show user a file path it work in single upload. When i try to change it to multiple file uplaod, the process crashing. I google it for solution in 7 hours i can't find any thing best regards. Yes I debugged it the ViewBag turns a null...

Comment: where is 'publicPath' declared?

Comment: My bad here it's between with using and for `string[] publicPath = new string[] { "/images/" + fileName };`

Comment: So in the privacy Action in the controller change TempData["link"] as List<string> to TempData["link"] as string[].

Comment: Got it, but it shows an error.

Comment: can you share the error?... have a look at my answer as well, might be a better way of doing it

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. `@foreach (var item in Model)`

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention is to change the declaration of public path to be a string not an array of strings (string[]). So try this ...    string publicPath = "/images/" + fileName ;

Comment: Ok, i change it but same problem sir..

Comment: can you update your post to include the new code?

Comment: Yes,sir. I'm on my way. UPDATED @GlynnHurrell

Comment: I can see you are still declaring publicPath as string[] ... change it to....  string publicPath = "/images/" + fileName; (remove the [] to make it a single string)

Comment: I already deleted it.

Comment: have you also added '@model string[]' to the top of privacy.cshtml?

Comment: Yes sir I added @model top of Privacy.cshtml.

Comment: The only other thing that I can spot is that my original answer was missing a @ after model string [] at the top of cshtml. Copy and paste the code from my answer (I have updated with full code). I have been able to build and run your code without any errors so other than the above, you will have to look at debugging and using breakpoints to go through the code line by line and see where exactly it is failing. You should be looking for a value of NULL being output as this is the root cause of the 'Object reference' error

Comment: check out this for getting started debugging....https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-breakpoints?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 0):

As you are already passing the data to the View i.e. View(Data), then you can simply specify the Model in the View. So your privacy.cshtml will be:

```
@model string[]
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Privacy Policy";
}
<label>Link:</label>
<br />
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <textarea cols="102" rows="5" disabled="disabled" style="resize:none;">@item</textarea>
    <br />
}
```

And then in the controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace CheckMate.Web.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public int count;
        private readonly IConfiguration configuration;
        private readonly string _webRootPath;
        public string _dir;
        public HomeController(IConfiguration config, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            this.configuration = config;
            _webRootPath = env.WebRootPath;
        }
        public async Task<IActionResult> FileUpload(IEnumerable<IFormFile> files)
        {
            var targetFolder = Path.Combine(_webRootPath, "images");
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                count = 0;
                var fileName = $"{Guid.NewGuid()}.png";
                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(targetFolder, fileName), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                {
                    file.CopyTo(fileStream);
                    count++;
                }
                string publicPath = "/images/" + fileName;
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                {
                    List<string> test = new List<string>();
                    test.Add(publicPath.ToString());
                    TempData["link"] = test;
                }

            }
            return new RedirectResult(@"Privacy");
        }
        public IActionResult Privacy()   //Privacy name here is just example it can change
        {
            //TempData.Keep();
            return View(TempData["link"] as string[]);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code,it seems you use asp.net core 2.x.

Be sure set the `CheckConsentNeeded` false:

```
services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
{
    // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
    options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
});
```

Comment: Yes sir, it is set to true, now I changed it to false. I never touched it, but what will it do for me?